# Search field only search a specific taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

**Background:**
I am trying to build a cleaners directory website based on location. that you type for example "London" and next pages shows cleaners listed in London.

**Done so far:**
I have created a custom post "cleaners" and taxonomy "city" with the help of plugin and added London, birmingham and Oxford etc to it.

**Want to achieve:**
I am looking to create a "Location" search field that is ONLY linked with the "city" custom taxonomy. so people on typing London will only be able to see the post linked with that taxonomy. (currently I guess teh ) Ideally I'd like a type dropdown so when you just type "L" it displays suggestions in the dropdown.

Could anyone help me with that. I am still in a process of learning Wordpress. FYI this website would be similar to Justeat or flexioffice.

Thanks,
Sab

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: thats regular "twenty twelve" theme code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [search everything](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-everything/) plugin to add taxonomy in your search and it have some nice features that wordpress normal search don't have. Or you can use Relevanssi plugin.

Comment: Can I use it  to ONLY search that specific taxonomy?

Comment: Don't know specific taxonomy thing for search everything. you can use Relevanssi plugin to search only specific taxonomy.